# Select next highest data element in a series of values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has a list of individuals responsible for monetary thresholds. Table `Thresholds` looks like:

```
John Smith    5000.00
Carla Smith   3000.00
Anna Smith    1000.00
```

I am trying to craft a select statement where I can return the name of the individual for the next highest threshold. So I have an order that is for 1500.00. I want to return Carla's name since the value is above Anna's, but I don't want to see John as an option.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Can you provide more of a table example (with rows and columns) and then an example of the expected output?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tried using the space to get my post to look cleaner and apparently it's smarter than I am!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tried using the space to get my post to look cleaner and apparently it's smarter than I am!

    SELECT Name AS [Escalate To] FROM dbo.ThresholdLimits T JOIN dbo.Orders O ON T.Company=O.Company WHERE O.Company='Corp' AND T.Limit > O.Amount

and here is where I'm not sure to continue with my WHERE Clause.  Amount=1500.00, the limit the user has is 1000.00. SELECT should return name of next highest user, example, Anna has a limit of 1000, the order is 1500. The next highest authorized user is Carla, has a limit of 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(50),SomeValue int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('John Smith',5000),
('Carla Smith',3000),
('Anna Smith',1000)

;with cte as (
    Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Order by SomeValue) 
    From  @YourTable
    Where SomeValue >= 1500
)
Select * from cte where RN=1
```

Returns

```
Name        SomeValue   RN
Carla Smith 3000        1
```

Or has @James suggested (in case of a tie)

```
;with cte as (
    Select *,Rnk=Dense_Rank() over (Order by SomeValue) 
    From  @YourTable
    Where SomeValue >= 1500
)
Select * from cte where Rnk=1
```

Comment: aren't it be better to use dense_rank() instead Row_Number() just in can we get a tie.

Comment: @James Perhaps, but if they are setting tiers, they tend not to overlap.  Like chicken soup for a cold ... couldn't hurt.  :)

Comment: @James Included your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Using `TOP`:

```
Select top 1 * from table Where value >= 1500 order by value
```